# Hex 3 character to 2 character conversion

Tags: javascript, numbers, hex, decimal

Looking at a wireshark preview of some hex.

I see 32 35 36. It previews it as 256.

I thought the hex representation of 256 is 100. However the hex preview in wireshark is only two characters 1b 01 etc.

How is 256 encoded as 32 35 36? Where does the 3 come from? In javascript how would you represent a number such as 256 as a hex value encoded with a series of 2 characters?

Comment: all ascii hex is 2 chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32 35 36 are the hexadecimal representations of the ascii characters "2", "5", "6". You are right that the number 256 is 0x100, but, the characters "256" are correctly represented as 0x32 0x35 0x36, at least when encoded in ascii or utf8.

And to answer your javascript question, here's one way to do that mapping. (This will only work for 1-byte characters.)

`console.log("256".split('').map(d => d.charCodeAt().toString(16)));`